# SQL Server 2012 installing replication without a server restart

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to add replication to an existing instance of SQL Server 20212. I am running it as admin. When I select add new features and point it to the cd it says I must restart the server. Can I bypass the restart? The server is my production 24/7 machine. Can I add replication without restarting my server?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.